# Error while trying to display data using sqlite3 and flask

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask

I am trying to display a portfolio of stocks. The task is to access the database and then to lookup for the current price of the stock, displaying it, the total value of the stocks, the remaining cash from 10000 and the grand total, that should be changing depending on the current stock price.
I have tried various ways to access and display data but I am constantly having errors and I need a help, please. I have also tried to create a for loop and to append data to list but again without success.
The error is:
File "/home/ubuntu/finance/application.py", line 58, in index
current_price=lookup(row["symbol"]["price"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
My code is below:

```
   @app.route("/")
        @login_required
        def index():
        
            """Show portfolio of stocks"""
            #Access the stocks of the current user from DB
            rows=db.execute("SELECT symbol, name, sum(shares) as shares FROM stocks WHERE user_id=:user_id ORDER BY symbol", user_id=session["user_id"])
            #Check the current price of each stock using the helper function lookup and calculate the total cost of each stock( * number of shares by price)
            #add that info to rows and render it on the index page
            sum_total_cost=0
            for row in rows:
                #symbol=row["symbol"]
                #current_price=lookup(symbol["price"])
                current_price=lookup(row["symbol"]["price"])
                total_cost=current_price*(row["shares"])
                row["current_price"]=usd(current_price)
                row["total_cost"]=usd(total_cost)
                sum_total_cost+=total_cost
            #Check the current cash of the user
            user_id=session["user_id"]
            user = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=:user_id", user_id=user_id)
            cash=user[0]["cash"]
            grand_total = cash+sum_total_cost
        
            return render_template("index.html", rows=rows, cash = cash, grand_total=grand_total)
```

And HTML

{% extends "layout.html" %}

```
{% block title %}
    Index
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Symbol</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Shares</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Total Cost</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- TODO: Loop through the database to display all transactions and the balance -->
                        {% for row in rows %}
                           <tr>
                               <td>{{row.symbol}}
                               <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                               <td>{{row.shares}}</td>
                               <td>{{row.current_price}}</td>
                               <td>{{row.total_cost}}</td>
                         {% endfor %}

                           </tr>


                           <tr>
                               <th>Cash</th>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td>{{cash}}</td>

                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <th>Grand Total</th>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td>{{grand_total}}</td>

                           </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Lookup function

```
def lookup(symbol):
    """Look up quote for symbol."""

    # Contact API
    try:
        api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY")
        url = f"https://cloud-sse.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{urllib.parse.quote_plus(symbol)}/quote?token={api_key}"
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.RequestException:
        return None

    # Parse response
    try:
        quote = response.json()
        return {
            "name": quote["companyName"],
            "price": float(quote["latestPrice"]),
            "symbol": quote["symbol"]
        }
    except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
        return None
```

Comment: First of all, please state exactly what kind of "errors" you are having. Is this a Python/Flask error or the results are not what you want ?

Comment: I am sorry, just edited the original post. The current error is with python, while trying different approach earlier I was able to display data but the grand total value was never correct.

Comment: Shouldn't this `current_price=lookup(row["symbol"]["price"])`  read `current_price = lookup(row["symbol"])["price"]  (closing paren moved) since lookup returns a dict and you want the value of price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory, it should be that line that is causing the problem:

```
current_price=lookup(row["symbol"]["price"])
```

Since you are reading from a table you should very likely be using `row["symbol"]`, possibly transformed by some operation. You are addressing the field as if it were a dict. I don't know what your lookup does though. I would guess it takes just one argument so it could simply be something like that: `current_price=lookup(row["symbol"])`

Perhaps post the code for the lookup function if you don't manage to fix the issue.

PS: maybe the whole calculation could be done in SQL, probably a matter of JOINing two tables or something.

Comment: Thank you. I tested current_price=lookup(row["symbol"]) but it also did not work. Tested this as well: #symbol=row["symbol"]
        #current_price=lookup(symbol["price"]) but it is the same just using 2 lines. I am dding Lookup in original post as it is too long.

Comment: I solved it:))) With a small correction of the database. Thank you for the hint, Anonymous. This way of accessing data was too complicated for me and I am glad I found solution, I am able to fully understand.